# How to access HTTP Virtual XML In php

Tags: php, xml, http, post

I am developing a web application that handling stock module.

ie,
My client having a tally server with stock details. 
He is sending a **HTTP VIRTUAL XML** data on POST method.
He manually sending this data on a button click in Tally server.

the submitted url is like http://example.com/admin/tally/test.php and he is posting xml data to this URL.

He is telling that works perfect on his local server as http://localhost/admin/tally/test.php with the below code.

```
    <?php
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    if ( isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) )
    { 
    $fn = fopen("/test.txt","a");
    fwrite ($fn,$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    fclose($fn);

    print ("<RESPONSE>" );
    print ("<STATUS>Data Updated Successfully</STATUS>" );
    print ("</RESPONSE>" );
    }else{ 
    print ("<RESPONSE>" );
    print ("<STATUS>Link Not working</STATUS>" );
    print ("</RESPONSE>" );
   }

   ?>
```

But its not working in liver server.

I think its caused because **$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA**, its deprecated in php 5.6

Our php info is attaching this topic.

[image]

How can I solve this issue ?

Is there any issues with my Production server ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of PHP, the ini directive [`always_populate_raw_post_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) has been switched off by default. As you correctly mentioned, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`has been deprecated in PHP v5.6 and also been *removed* as of v7.0. The recommended way is to read from the [`php://input` stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) now.